# My nodeJS app is sending suspicious GET/POST requests. Do I have a virus?

Tags: node.js, express, web-applications, malware, virus

I have noticed that when using morgan with nodemon, if I leave the app running locally for a while, it will log strange GET and POST requests to different admin pages like phpmyadmin, dbadmin, typ3/phpmyadmin etc. Why is this happening? How can this happen?

My antivirus is not detecting anything wrong and except for some JS snipets in the client, I am using packages installed from npm.

Below are some screenshoots of the morgan logs.

[image]

[image]

I would like to deploy this app to production soon, but I am concerned about the suspicious requests being made to my server... Thanks!

EDIT: It turns out my port forwarding was on and these requests were coming from the outside.

Comment: Can you provide more context about where this app is deployed? Is it exposed to the internet? If it's running on a local network, is there perhaps a vulnerability scanner? That might be the case if you are running this at your office. I would advise asking your colleagues if that fits your situation.

Comment: Hi. I am running it locally on my personal windows machine. There is no port forwarding from the outside to the port I am using (3000).

Comment: as all of the requests get 404 it seems a crawler or scanner is running and scanning your machine! what's your project and dependent libraries ? are you sure about that this requests is from your app ? maybe you are a victim of botnet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a tool like [TCPView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) to determine where those connections are coming from.

Either they're external and you do have a port forwarded or something on your local network, or they're on your own machine and TCPView will indicate which executable they're coming from.

Comment: Hi! I rechecked my port-forwarding and it was on. My mistake. I turned it on a while ago to try and application on my mobile phone and left in on.
Looks like basically there are some bots out scanning ports on random IP-Addresses.